# ora 01031 insufficient privileges in oracle while creating view

Tags: oracle11g

Error received when creating a view:
`ora 01031 insufficient privileges` 
Example:

```
SQL> create view wiew1
  2  as select ename from emp;
create view wiew1
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Well, then the user you are logged in as does not have rights to create a view.  Contact your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the create_view or create_any_view privilege.  See your DBA.  If you have DBA privileges do:

```
grant create_view,create_any_view on [user name] ;
```

That will solve the problem.